# Various ways of installing docker on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, docker

On Ubuntu, you can install docker using any of the three commands, I know about the ce and ee versions, but what is the different between docker.io and other commands.

`sudo apt-get -y install docker.io
sudo apt-get -y install docker-ce
sudo apt-get -y install docker-ee`

Thanks

Comment: `docker.io` is for old version. For the latest version there are only 2 options `docker-ce` & `docker-ee`. If you are going for enterprise edition you have to use `docker-ee` & if you are going to install free version then you have to install `docker-ce`.

Comment: ok thanks!, what about docker-engine, isn't that the older version. I see at most places docker.io is used.

Comment: That is even older than that, previously we have to configure whole machine to install `docker-engine` after that all of it got automated as part of the `docker.io` package.

Comment: oh!, thanks. May be i should move to using docker-ce

Comment: @patrikshah yours should be an answer, I would upvote it

Comment: yes, I will accept it

Comment: Only docker.io seems to be available via the normal package repositories (checked 16.04 and 16.10). What are you doing that you see docker-ce and docker-ee? I thought those were only available via docker.com's package repository.